# Permutations & combination generating algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, set, permutation, combinations

I m suppose to write down an algorithm for printing out all possible combinations of given pairs of ‘<>’, I have tried to developed an algorithm to work this out but I think that’s not correct, because I do realize this problem is related to permutations [nPr] & let’s say for a given input of 5 it should create 120 combinations (5P5=120) but my code is only generating 81.

`In my code have tried to generate all possible combinations by placing every element at every place one by one, but now I am little confused about how correct this approach is?`

Thing is Most likely am not able to grasp the real concept of 'making subsets/combinations/permutations' (though theoretically I know what they are and how to calculate them)

I am not looking for a complete final "spoon feeded code", but something that could explain me ‘what I should be doing’, from which I could extract out the steps, understand concept and can develop my own.

`If possible something extending or tweaking my current coding to achieve the right result would be easier for me to understand.`

```
void permute()
{
    string str=”<><><>”;
    char buck=' ';
for(int a=0;a<str.length()-1;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<str.length()-1;b++){
            cout<<str<<endl;
            buck=str[b];
            str[b]=str[b+1];
            str[b+1]=buck;
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying to understand what I should do but i'am still struggling, any help or guidance would be really helpful.
Thankyou

---

`From 'all combinations' i mean printing out all the possible ways given set of characters can be arranged, lets say for 2 pairs '<><>' it should be like: <><>,><<>,><<>,><><,<<>>,>><< ... ... ...`

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/generating-permutations.shtml as well as 'recursively generating permutations'.

Comment: Could you give in example for say n=2? Im not sure what you mean exactly by all combinations of <>

Comment: Permuations and combinations are different things which require different algorithms. You should make it clear which one you want.

Comment: Is `><><><` valid solution? If not - you have `Cn(n/2)` possibilities, where `Cn` denotes the [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

Comment: @jozefg: i have edited my question please have a look.

Comment: @john: I'm looking for all possible combinations where order does matter like <><> is not equal to <<>>, hence i think more specifically i should call them permutations?

Comment: @amit: for '<><><>' this ` ><><><` is a valid solution. Catalan number can you bit a little more detail in how i can achieve that result?

Comment: @Maven: Then you are asking for a standard permutation. There is a lot of details on it out there. Your edit clarifies it has nothing to do with the catalan number.

Comment: @amit: Thank you for directing my problem in the right direction.
yeah Ive been searching for permutations in general and its programming to be specific even few questions her eon Stackoverflow but ive failed to understand `how permutations are being generated` probably i can find a ready code for that on internet but i want to grasp the concept of writing and designing that algorithm. to clear the discussion i would ask you: `how close is my code to the 'one' that generates permutations` have i done 10% of work towards that or my code is totally useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ provides `bool std::next_permutation(Iterator first, Iterator last)` that modifies the content of (first, last) to be the next permutation in the sequence, returning true if there are more permutations, or false if this is the last permutation. The list needs to be sorted first (using `std::sort(Iterator first, Iterator last)`), and the sorted list forms the first permutation.

You can interact with these algorithms using `str.begin()` and `str.end()`.

**NOTE:** Because your data set contains duplicate items, not all permutations are possible (some will be duplicates of other entries). That is:

```
string : permutations
-------:-------------
abcd   : 24
<><>   : 6
abcdef : 720
<><><> : 20
```

If you really want all permutations (including duplicates), you can have an `int indices = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` array which you run the permutations on and then print `str[indices[0]]` through `str[indices[5]]` for each permutation.

This could give you an insight into your algorithm and what is going wrong. That is, it can serve as a reference to compare your algorithm against.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test it has 42 solutions:

```
    function placeBrackets(n)
    {
        var placeBracketsRecur = function(prefix, remainingOpen, remainingClosed)
        {
            if(remainingClosed == 0)
            {
                document.write(prefix + "<br/>");
                return;
            }

            if(remainingOpen > 0)
            {
                placeBracketsRecur(prefix + "(",  remainingOpen - 1, remainingClosed);
            }

            if(remainingOpen < remainingClosed)
            {
                placeBracketsRecur(prefix + ")",  remainingOpen, remainingClosed - 1);
            }
        }

        placeBracketsRecur("", n, n);
    }
```

///output

```
((((()))))
(((()())))
(((())()))
(((()))())
(((())))()
((()(())))
((()()()))
((()())())
((()()))()
((())(()))
((())()())
((())())()
((()))(())
((()))()()
(()((())))
(()(()()))
(()(())())
(()(()))()
(()()(()))
(()()()())
(()()())()
(()())(())
(()())()()
(())((()))
(())(()())
(())(())()
(())()(())
(())()()()
()(((())))
()((()()))
()((())())
()((()))()
()(()(()))
()(()()())
()(()())()
()(())(())
()(())()()
()()((()))
()()(()())
()()(())()
()()()(())
()()()()()
```